# Finding strings (including its special character) after keyword in python

Tags: python, regex, keyword-search

Suppose I have a text that looks like this

```
text = No. ADJ.TRM/085/BFG/2015
```

the output that I wanted is ADJ.TRM/085/BFG/2015

I have tried using

```
re.search('(?<=No. )(\w+)',text)
```

It gives me only ADJ

also tried

```
re.search('No.\s\w+\s\w+\s(\w+)',text)
```

It gives me an error

Comment: try, ``No\.(.+)`` ?

Comment: Many rules map to regular expressions that generate the string you want returned. Here are a few such rules: return the remainder of the string beginning with: 1) the second capital letter; 2) the first capital letter following the first period; 3) the first capital letter following `"No."` at the beginning of the string followed by one or more spaces. The title refers to a "keyword". In your example is that `"No"`? `"No."`?, `"No. "`? Must the desired text begin immediately after the keyword?...

Comment: ...You need to give us the rule you wish applied, not the desired result for a single example, asking us to somehow reverse-engineer that result to identify the rule to be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
if match := re.search("No\. (.*)", text):
    print(match.group(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends on the exact format of your string but, as given, you can simply do this:

```
text = 'No. ADJ.TRM/085/BFG/2015'

print(text.split()[1])
```

**Output:**

```
ADJ.TRM/085/BFG/2015
```

Answer (score 0):

`\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

This excludes the `.` and the `/` that you are also trying to match.

While `.*` will work, if you're trying to be deliberate, then you can use a slight modification of your pattern to make it work:

```
>>> re.search('(?<=No. )([\w./]+)',text)
<re.Match object; span=(4, 24), match='ADJ.TRM/085/BFG/2015'>
>>>
```

`[\w./]` instead of `\w` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_./]`